# Drupal + Lighttpd: enabling clean urls (rewriting)

Tags: lighttpd, drupal

I'm emulating Ubuntu on my mac, and I use it as a server.

I've installed lighttpd + Drupal and the following configuration section requires a domain name in order to make clean urls to work.

Since I'm using a local server I don't have a domain name and I was wondering how to make it work given the fact the ip of the local machine is usually changing.

thanks

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)mywebsite\.com" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www/sites/mywebsite"
  server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/mywebsite/error.log"
  server.name = "mywebsite.com"
  accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/mywebsite/access.log"
  include_shell "./drupal-lua-conf.sh mywebsite.com"

  url.access-deny += ( "~", ".inc", ".engine", ".install", ".info",
       ".module", ".sh", "sql", ".theme",
       ".tpl.php", ".xtmpl", "Entries",
       "Repository", "Root" )


  # "Fix" for Drupal SA-2006-006, requires lighttpd 1.4.13 or above
  # Only serve .php files of the drupal base directory
  $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/.*/.*\.php$" {
      fastcgi.server = ()
      url.access-deny = ("")
  }

  magnet.attract-physical-path-to = ("/etc/lighttpd/drupal-lua-scripts/p-.lua")

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest (quick&dirty) way is to edit your hosts file: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/ Add: `10.10.10.1 mywebsite.com` Replace 10.10.10.1 with the IP of your Ubuntu instance.

Comment: It is not enough. I also have to add it to Ubuntu network configuration. Because I need to use it in configuration file. And since the ip changes, I should update twice the ips on both operating systems...